# Use prev for a distant selector

Tags: jquery

I am using Zurb Foundation and it's probably why I am getting this issue.
Here's my HTML code:

```
<div class="row collapse">
    <label for="">Login</label>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-2 columns">
        <span class="prefix"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="large-11 medium-11 small-10 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like to add another class to the prefix span when I focus on the input. I tried the prev function, but it does not work because of the div in between.

Here's my jQuery code:

```
$('input').focus(function() {
    $(this).prev('.prefix').addClass('prefix-focus');
});
```

Any idea what I can do?

Thanks a lot

Comment: If the answer is not working or you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: Thanks Ammar, this works perfectly. I have another issue now, but I will create another topic. closest is better than parents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Traverse up to the overall container using `closest()`
2. Search for the span using `find()`

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
  $(this).closest('.row').find('.prefix').addClass('prefix-focus');
});
```

```css
.prefix-focus {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row collapse">
  <label for="">Login</label>
  <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-2 columns">
    <span class="prefix"><i class="fa fa-user">in prefix</i></span>
  </div>
  <div class="large-11 medium-11 small-10 columns">
    <input type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access that `span` directly like this

```js
$('input').focus(function() {
  $('span.prefix').addClass('prefix-focus');
});
```

```css
.prefix-focus {
  color: #F89A0C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row collapse">
    <label for="">Login</label>
    <div class="large-1 medium-1 small-2 columns">
        <span class="prefix"><i class="fa fa-user">TextColor</i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="large-11 medium-11 small-10 columns">
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```